# Columns with same height fot the title under one image. Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, height, multiple-columns

I really can't to have the same height for the grey part about the title under the image about the car.
I wish that if the text is a lot, like in the first box, the other boxes take the same height of the first one.

I had tryed with all the methods found in this community but wasn't work.

http://s3.postimg.org/kjp2kesf7/Schermata_2015_08_26_alle_11_43_53.png

Can Someone help me?

```css
/* ==========================================================================
   VETRINA AUTO
   ========================================================================== */

#vetrina-auto .box-vetrina {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 background: #ffffff;
}

#vetrina-auto .row-auto {
 padding: 50px 0px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

/* ===================================
   Button
   =================================== */

#vetrina-auto .box-vetrina aside img {
 padding-top: 38%;
 margin-bottom: 0%;
 margin: auto;
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=60);
 -moz-opacity: 0.6;
 -khtml-opacity: 0.6;
 opacity: 0.6;
}


#vetrina-auto .box-vetrina aside a:hover img {
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=10);
 -moz-opacity: 1;
 -khtml-opacity: 1;
 opacity: 1;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

/* ===================================
   Box Auto
   =================================== */

#vetrina-auto .box-auto {
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 color: #585f63;
 margin-bottom: 0%;

}

#vetrina-auto .box-auto img {
 border: 1px solid #585f63;
 width: 100%;
}

/* ===================================
   Testi
   =================================== */

#vetrina-auto .box-auto h3 {
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 1em;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em;
 padding: 5px 5px;
 margin: 0px;
 background: #585f63;
 color: #ffffff;
}

#vetrina-auto .box-auto p {
 font-size: 1.1em;
 font-weight: 500;
 letter-spacing: 0.05em;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 5px 0px;
}

#vetrina-auto .box-auto .prezzo {
 font-size: 1.4em;
 font-weight: 600;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

/* ===================================
   Icona
   =================================== */

#vetrina-auto a .box-auto-hover i {
 margin-top: 32%;
}

#vetrina-auto a .box-auto-hover {
 color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 opacity: 0;
 background-color: transparent;
 -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 opacity:0.0;
}




/* ===================================
   Hover Button
   =================================== */

#vetrina-auto .box-vetrina aside a:hover img {
 -webkit-filter: opacity(100%); /* Google Chrome e Apple Safari */
 -moz-filter: opacity(100%); /* Mozilla Firefox */
 -ms-filter: opacity(100%); /* Microsoft Internet Explorer */
 -o-filter: opacity(100%); /* Opera */
 filter: opacity(100%); /* La proprietà standard */

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

/* ===================================
   Hover Box Auto
   =================================== */

#vetrina-auto a:hover .box-auto {
 color: #333a3d;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#vetrina-auto a:hover .box-auto img {
 background-color: white;
 -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=40);
 opacity:0.4;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

/* ===================================
   Hover Testi
   =================================== */

#vetrina-auto a:hover .box-auto h3 {
 background: #363f48;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#vetrina-auto a:hover .box-auto .prezzo {
 font-weight: 800;
}

#vetrina-auto a:hover .box-auto p {
 font-weight: 600;
}

/* ===================================
   Hover Icona
   =================================== */

#vetrina-auto a:hover .box-auto-hover {
 color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 opacity: 1;
 background-zcolor: transparent;
 -ms-filter:z"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=10)";
 filter: alpzha(opacity=1);
 opacity:1.0z;
      z
 text-shadow: 0 0 20px #000000;
 text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="it"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <!-- Metatag -->
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta name="author" content="Ruggero Carrara - RBNZ Visual Art">
     <meta name="language" content="it">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#122a44">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-144x144.png">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 50px;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
            }
        </style>

        <!-- Stili CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home-page.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css">

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->


      

<!-- !AUTO IN VETRINA -->
 <div class="container">
  <div id="vetrina-auto" class="row">
   <div class="box-vetrina section-shadow">

    <!-- !Usato -->
    <div class="row-auto clearfix">
     <aside class="tipologia col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <a href="#" role="button"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/vetrina-auto/button-usato.jpg" alt="Immagine Bottone Usato" title="Scopri tutto il nostro Usato!" /></a>
     </aside>

           <!-- Auto 1 -->
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <a href="#">
             <div class="box-auto">
              <img src="img/icons/new.png" alt="Nuova Aggiunta" style="position: absolute;width: 40%;left: 0;top: 0;border: 0px;"><!-- NEW -->
        <div class="box-auto-hover"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-search-plus"></i></div><!-- /icona hover -->
        <img class="img-responsive section-shadow" src="img/vetrina-auto/segnaposto/segnaposto-1.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        <h3>VOLKSWAGEN Golf Business 1.6 TDI Blue DSG 5p. Comfortline</h3>
        <p>Benzina 3.8 CV</p>
        <p class="prezzo">30.900€</p>
             </div><!-- /box-auto -->
            </a>
           </div>
           <!-- /Auto 1 -->

           <!-- Auto 2 -->
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <a href="#">
             <div class="box-auto">
        <div class="box-auto-hover"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-search-plus"></i></div><!-- /icona hover -->
        <img class="img-responsive section-shadow" src="img/vetrina-auto/segnaposto/segnaposto-2.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        <h3>AUDI A4 Avant</h3>
        <p>Benzina 3.8 CV</p>
        <p class="prezzo">30.900€</p>
             </div><!-- /box-auto -->
            </a>
           </div>
           <!-- /Auto 2 -->

           <!-- Auto 3 -->
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <a href="#">
             <div class="box-auto">
        <div class="box-auto-hover"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-search-plus"></i></div><!-- /icona hover -->
        <img class="img-responsive section-shadow" src="img/vetrina-auto/segnaposto/segnaposto-3.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        <h3>AUDI A4 Avant</h3>
        <p>Benzina 3.8 CV</p>
        <p class="prezzo">30.900€</p>
             </div><!-- /box-auto -->
            </a>
           </div>
           <!-- /Auto 3 -->

           <!-- Auto 4 -->
           <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <a href="#">
             <div class="box-auto">
              <img src="img/icons/new.png" alt="Nuova Aggiunta" style="position: absolute;width: 40%;left: 0;top: 0;border: 0px;"><!-- NEW -->
        <div class="box-auto-hover"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-search-plus"></i></div><!-- /icona hover -->
        <img class="img-responsive section-shadow" src="img/vetrina-auto/segnaposto/segnaposto-4.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        <h3>AUDI A4 Avant</h3>
        <p>Benzina 3.8 CV</p>
        <p class="prezzo">30.900€</p>
             </div><!-- /box-auto -->
            </a>
           </div>
           <!-- /Auto 4 -->

           <!-- Auto 5 -->
           <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <a href="#">
             <div class="box-auto">
              <img src="img/icons/new.png" alt="Nuova Aggiunta" style="position: absolute;width: 40%;left: 0;top: 0;border: 0px;"><!-- NEW -->
        <div class="box-auto-hover"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-search-plus"></i></div><!-- /icona hover -->
        <img class="img-responsive section-shadow" src="img/vetrina-auto/segnaposto/segnaposto-5.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        <h3>AUDI A4 Avant</h3>
        <p>Benzina 3.8 CV</p>
        <p class="prezzo">30.900€</p>
             </div><!-- /box-auto -->
            </a>
           </div>
           <!-- /Auto 5 -->

    </div>
    <!-- Usato -->


   </div><!-- row-vetrina -->
  </div><!-- row -->
 </div><!-- container -->
<!-- /AUTO IN VETRINA -->





<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use attribute min-height, in every boxes, so you'll have all boxes at the same minimal height.

Comment: Ok, thanks @mautrok for the reply, but I wish that the height about all the columns in that row change and take the height of the column with more text, not with a fixed max width.

Comment: it's difficult to catch the right size because the attrtibute height is set to "auto" when it have that behaviour... you can revisit you're html code and make a div for all the boxes.

Comment: How can I revisit it? I really don't know how to do it.. Sorry